# How to automatically pick last 3 years from MySQL database column?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date

I have a MySQL database in which I count and select the 3 last years to display statistics.

I do this statically for each passing year like this:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM column WHERE category = 'something' AND YEAR(date) = '2015'"); 
$res = $db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()'); 
$result= (int) $res->fetchColumn();
```

What I would like to do is insert a code that automatically picks the last 3 years of data from the database and displays it. I don't have enough data in the DB to test3 years back in time, but searching around gave me this clue:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM column WHERE category = 'something' AND MyDate > date_sub(now(), interval 3 year
```

Any thoughts, tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM column WHERE category = 'something' where YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR));
```

Comment: I thought there would be a problem with two WHERE clauses, but that one went straight through, thank you!